# PHP ZipArchive Problems

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a project which uses the PHPExcel lib to do some export stuff. It relies on the zip extension to create archives.

While running it threw an error stating the ZipArchive class was not defined.

Fair enough.

I installed and checked the extension, created a test.php file on the server which   instantiates a ZipArchive and var_dumps it to the screen. It works. Everything appears to be installed correctly.

However the PHPExcel lib still throws the error. Why?

EDIT:
Playing around a little further - get_declared_classes() is showing ZipArchive in the array. When called from within the class its not.

Comment: Are you running the erroneous script from the command line, and the test script through the web server?

Comment: No, both through the web server under the same user.

Comment: If you execute a `phpinfo()` from the webserver , do you see `php_zip` extension installed?

Comment: Yes - http://cl.ly/image/2f2l2W1Z2Y03

Comment: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php#L94 The string it's creating is ZipArchive, and i've manually overridden it myself. Still same